# Get List of items from api endpont

Tags: node.js, json, api

Get request from API
How can i achive this kind of api using node JS

```
POST REQUEST TO /ADDFOOD
{
foodname : 'Foodname',
.
.
. 
ingredients : { 
  {name: 'abc' , price: 50},
  {name: 'abc3' , price: 60},
  {name: 'abc1' , price: 40},
 }
}
```

ingredients can be 1,2, 3 or more

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: API endpoint to add food ........ and there are some information with single vale like food name , price , etc ........ and IDK how to add multiple values to API endpoint like ingredient list ,  length of the list is unknown